# jQuery datetimepicker - Disable/hide time sliders after date selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I'm using the jQuery `datetimepicker` from [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) link. 
The sliders for hour and minute are activated.

How can I disable and hide both sliders, when the user selects a date that is more than X days away from today?

Example:

Max range for hour / minute usage: 2 weeks

- User selects 01/05/2014 - hour / minute still enabled / shown, user can select both.
- User selects 01/01/2014 - hour / minute should be disabled / hide the moment he selects this date.

Comment: You've got an `onSelect` method, and `showMinute` and `showHours` options. Did you try to combine something with that ? Do you have a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Most of the time i code with Java, i just added the Datepicker without changing much (pretty much a beginner in JS/jQuery). Never used JSFiddle, but i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/JUM4R/6/

Comment: Well, I tried also :  http://jsfiddle.net/2Kp56/64/ . I can change other options, like currentText, the way you did, but was not able to change the showMinute option...